# Javascript replace with regular expression error for $0 in IE11

Tags: javascript, regex, internet-explorer-11

I have a string and message:

```
str = "Test $0 $1 $2";
message = "Hi %2 Hello %2" ;
```

Now I want to replace all `%2` to `str` in message. I am using RegExp as below,

```
message = message.replace(new RegExp("%2" , "g"), str);
```

It is working fine in Chrome and Firefox and message is coming as expected

```
message = "Hi Test $0 $1 $2 Hello $0 $1 $2"
```

But in Internet Explorer 11, it is giving incorrect value for message like

```
message = "Hi Test %2 $1 $2 Hello %2 $1 $2"
```

In IE11 , `$0` (sub string of str) is replacing with `%2`. Any one can please suggest me on this.

Comment: You may want to look at the documentation for [`replace`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace#Specifying_a_string_as_a_parameter). It looks like you need to escape your `$` characters.

Comment: your code is wron, `"%2"` is always replaced with `"Test $0 $1 $2"`, so, the resulting string is: `"Hi Test $0 $1 $2 Hello ` **`Test`** `$0 $1 $2"`

Comment: Replace $0 with $&, it will work in any browser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this, it will help you

```js
var str = 'Test $0 $1 $2';
message = "Hi %2 Hello %2";
var regx = new RegExp("%2", "g");
if (str.indexOf("$") > 0) {
  var val = str[str.indexOf("$") + 1];
  if (val.trim() != "" && val.trim() != "$") {
    var rex = new RegExp(val, "g");
    str = str.replace(rex, "$$" + val);
  }
}
message = message.replace(new RegExp("%2", "g"), str);
alert(message);
```

Comment: Working Fine. Thanks Vijay

Answer (score 2):

In replacement strings (the second argument to `String#replace`), the dollar sign `$` serves a special function, and so each one must be escaped using a preceding dollar sign. Thus, your `str` should be:

```
var str = 'Test $$0 $$1 $$2'
```

I don't think that the exact function of the dollar sign is too relevant to you at the moment, but if you'd like to learn more about the purposes it serves you can visit [this documentation page on the Mozilla Development Network](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace#Specifying_a_string_as_a_parameter).

**Snippet:**

```js
var str = "Test $$0 $$1 $$2",
    message = "Hi %2 Hello %2"

message = message.replace(/%2/g, str)

console.log(message)
```